# How do I use Eloquent to get all relationships from an intermediate table?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have many to many relationships, eg:

```
// Category Model
class Category extends Model
{
    public function sections()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Section');
    }
}

// Section Model
class Section extends Model
{
    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category');
    }
}
```

Let's say I have the following category / section relationships with the following slugs:

```
domestic
    dogs
    cats
    birds
zoo
    cats
    birds
winged
    birds
```

Is there an Eloquent or easy way to list all of the sections with their category?

To put this in context, if category and section had a slug, based on my example, I would like to get a list of sections like this:

```
domestic/dogs
domestic/cats
domestic/birds
zoo/cats
zoo/birds
winged/birds
```

I have tried to create a Pivot model by extending the Pivot class but can't work it out.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could do the trick:

```php
// Retrieve all categories
$categories = Category::with('sections')->all();

// Define result array
$result = [];

foreach ($categories as $category) {
    foreach ($category->sections as $section) {
        $result[] = $category->slug . '/' . $section->slug;
    }
}

// Result now holds the contents you are looking for
```

Comment: Thank you @Maarten Veerman. Yes, it does the trick. Though I was hoping for an Eloquent solution. Something less taxing on a large database.